# Set Document version

Tags: document, version

I would to migrate documents from System A to SharePoint, but my customer wants me to set the latest document in SharePoint. So for example:

The document has version 3.1, the customer wants me to add this document in SharePoint version 3.1. Is this possible?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

When you add a document in a SharePoint library with versioning enabled it will be in version 0.1.

You can't jump directly to version 3.1 but you can increase the version after uploading by editing the document until you reach the version you want. Then you can remove the version history.

Depending on your case and how many documents you have you'll probably need a script to do this for you instead of doing it manually for every document.

Comment: Could you somehow manually manipulate the version number by putting the file directly into the appropriate `_vti_history` folder?

Comment: Do you have any idea where a script to do this can be found?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable document versioning in document Library. Go to Library settings -> Versioning settings  -> Document Version History. Select **Create major and minor (draft) versions**